# Why is this regex match failing

Tags: regex, c++11

I am using the following code and the regex match is failing

```
std::regex reg("^Program Files");
if(std::regex_match("Program Files (x86)",reg)
{
  return true;
}
```

I tried this regex [here](https://regex101.com/) and it seems to work. Any suggestions why my if condition is not returning true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `regex_search()`, not `regex_match()`. The `regex_match()` function always matches against the complete string.